# jQuery getting value from a drop down selected

Tags: jquery

traditionally we write

```
var value = $("#drop-down-id").val();
```

to get the value.
IN my case, some of the options contains multiple words with spaces like
"Allow All","Internet Users" etc. 
What I am getting in VALUE is only "Allow" that is, jquery is trimming off words after the white space. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could include the HTML for your drop down showing the exact values as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the value wrapped in the `<option></option>` and you don't use the val attribute directly, you can do:

```
var value = $('#drop-down-id option:selected').text();
```

Comment: Might have worked for you, but please know the difference. the text() attribute gets what the DropDownList currently displays, whereas the val() attribute is the "behind" value. <option value="value">text</option>

Comment: Thats a very good point.. I checked in firebug, the "value" had been trimmed to one word. So, the .text was working and not the .value().
Basically i m populating it dynamically from a json object. Will have to check it out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

try with:

```
var value = $("#drop-down-id option:selected").attr("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense. There should not be any need to get the option text. If you need to do so, then your option elements are likely populated the wrong way in the server side.

Check the HTML source, you're likely forgotten the quotes around the option's value attribute.

This one is *wrong*:

```
<option value=John Doe>John Doe</option>
```

It would only return the first word as the actually selected value, because the space is actually an attribute separator in HTML; now you'll get "John" as value and the "Doe" is seen as another (non-existing ) HTML attribute.

This one is *correct*

```
<option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
```

This way you'll get "John Doe" as value.